# how to refresh/reload only once after the page is loaded in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

how to refresh/reload only once after the page is loaded in jquery mobile. because am using wow slider and when it is loaded the data is getting dynamically but the ui is not correctly getting once the page is refreshed it is getting. Can someone help me for this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this... This works for me. May be it will work for you also. Just include this script in your 'data-role="page" div' available in your mobile jquery page.

Below is test1.html:

```
<body>
<a href="test.html">test</a> <!--This link redirects to test.html but you will see 'test.html#' at address bar that means you page is reloaded once -->
 </body>
```

test.html:

```
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
if(location.hash != 'test1.html'){
location = 'test.html#';    
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try this.
 <body onload="if (location.href.indexOf('#')==-1)   {location.replace(location.href+'#')}">